# Setting up Documents folder prior to UI Testing

Tags: xctest, xcode-ui-testing

XCTest UI Automation testing is pretty powerful stuff, until you need to test some portion of the UI that presents itself differently based on some data.  For instance, our app stores data in the `Documents` folder.  Setting that data up programmagically in the test is pretty painful.

I know that we don't have access to the app's `Documents` folder from the UI test app.  I'm looking for ideas on how to accomplish setting up the app for UI testing.  We currently have a launch argument parameter that essentially blows away the contents of the Documents folder.  I would like to do that plus copy over specific files.

I feel like maybe this can be done as part of the UI Target build phase, but I'm not sure how to target the simulator device selected in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

I made a function in my production code to setup some test data. I'm calling it only when running UI tests. In the function, I have an if check like this:

```swift
func setupTestData() {
    let testMode = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.contains("testMode")
    if !testMode { return }
    // do any setup here
}
```

In your UI tests:

```swift
override func setUpWithError() throws {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launchArguments = ["testMode"]
    app.launch()
}
```

I am new to iOS, and this is the only way I found to setup data for UI tests. It doesn't feel clean, and it feels like there should be a better way, but at least it works.